# Redelivery Policy Is Not Working in Activemq Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have used below configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class NotificationApplication {
    @Value("${jms.broker.endpoint}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(NotificationApplication.class, args);
        RecordReader abc = ctx.getBean(RecordReader.class);
        abc.readNotifications();
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(env.getProperty("jms.redelivery.maximum", Integer.class));
        factory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
        factory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList("com.lms.notification"));
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws Throwable {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        factory.setConcurrency(env.getProperty("jms.connections.concurrent"));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
        template.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
}
```

The issue is the Redelivery policy is not working as I have defined in activeMQConnectionFactory bean. Means I have set maximum redelivery 1, but is not being redelivered in case of exception in listener. Also in case of exception in listener it should go to the default DLQ, which is also not happening. But if I comment the jmsListenerContainerFactory bean all works fine.
I am not able to identify why this is happening. Can any one look into this what wrong I am doing?
I am using Activemq 5.16.1
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking others to debug your code?  Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Hi Tim, Earlier I was getting other issue that My Listener giving exception MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to NotificationModel.when i was using the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory bean, i not using this it was working fine.

Comment: I debug and found that in PayloadMethodArgumentResolver Class<?> this line was returning payloadClass = payload.getClass(); String which should return my model class.So i resolve this by adding factory.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter()); this line.Now after this all worked fine but as i mentioned Redelivery policy  stopped working.Although it i being passed in object when it is calling bean activeMQConnectionFactory. Now no exception is coming so not able to identify where to start debug. So i thought there might be some configuration issue in my bean declarion.

Comment: I googled the same problem but could not get if this issue faced by anyone. Can you let me know where to debug so that i can check once.

Comment: Hi Team, Can please anyone give me some hint on this. I tried to find out the issue but no luck. Some where i read that with DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory  bean redelivery policy does not work. I again emphasis on that with DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory  redelivery policy not working if i comment this, then working. Thank